# Continuous replication between Oracle Database and Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication, azure-sql-database

Background info: Our core ERP has its data on Oracle. Our own applications are Microsoft SQL Server based.

Almost every application reads data from this Oracle database and usually there is some sort of synchronisation where we copy the entire database.

When looking around there are numerous solutions. Most of these seem deprecated. (e.g. Oracle GoldenGate).

Our Oracle database is on-premise and we intend to use Azure SQL Database for our future applications.

What is currently the best way to set-up this synchronisation?

- Master: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
- Slave: Azure SQL Database

I must have assumed that Oracle GoldenGate was deprecated since I've seen lots of old posts but hardly any recent ones. But this is another 'tool' to keep our data in sync. Are there other/better solutions?

Perhaps a linked server is an option in my case? Is that possible with Oracle on-prem and Azure SQL Database?

Is GoldenGate the **best** option if you want replication?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Golden Gate has always supported [replication between Oracle and SQL Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/oracle-sqlserver-goldengate-460262.html). For a project I recently confirmed that Golden Gate for Oracle 10 is still available if you push a bit.  If you are using an Oracle version that is out of support then you need to update for a number of reasons.

Synchronization with Azure is detailed here:

[Configuring Oracle GoldenGate for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/configure-oracle-golden-gate/)